# NullPointerException in Request.notifyAttributeAssigned

Tags: java, servlets

I am not sure what's wrong with this code snippet:

```
public class RequestProcessor extends Thread{
    private ServletContext context;
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    public RequestProcessor(ServletContext servletContext, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.context = servletContext;
        this.request = request;
        this.response = response;
        handler = HandlerFactory.getFactory(request);

        start();            
    }

    public void run(){
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");

        try {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

These threads are enqueued [method `enqueue()`] in a `ArrayBlockingQueue` and parameters are taken from a normal `HttpServlet`.

So, the doGet() from the HttpServlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    scheduler.enqueue(getServletContext(), request, response);
}
```

I have a Java exception, there's a problem with with the forwarding.

What's wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**

Take a look to this stack trace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet RequestDispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1563)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.access$000(Request.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request$3.set(Request.java:3369)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1515)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at source.RequestProcessor.run(RequestProcessor.java:42)
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1563)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.access$000(Request.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request$3.set(Request.java:3369)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1515)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.setAttribute(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:286)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at source.RequestProcessor.run(RequestProcessor.java:42)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "there's a problem with the forward"? By the way, it's a terrible idea to catch exceptions and not even log them.

Comment: Humm, this is not the real code, it's just a demo (for the logs). I mean, my dispatcher is supposed to forward my request to /index.jsp in this example. Instead of it, I have an exception.. This kind of exception: at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)

Comment: Ah, you hadn't said there was an exception. Now you've shown a bit of a stack trace, but not what the actual exception is, or what the message is. Please edit these details into your question, and also please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: Yeah, I know.. Ok I just edited my initial post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, looking at the code again, I think I understand what's wrong.

When `doGet` returns, I suspect that Tomcat expects that you're done with the request and the response - so it may well be clearing all kinds of information which is required within `forward`... as well as returning data to the client, of course.

I don't believe request/response pairs are designed to be used this way in servlets - not without specific support where you would specify that even though `doGet` has completed, the container shouldn't consider the request complete.

Think of it this way: if you had an *empty* `doGet` method, what would you expect to happen to the request/response, and the network connection? Now consider that all you're doing is starting a new thread which maintains references to those objects - why would you expect the container to hold off from sending a response to the client?

It's not really clear why you're doing this in the first place, rather than just calling `forward` within the `doGet` method, but if you *do* want to hand the work off to another thread, you'll need to find some way of telling the container about it. (I know there are containers which support this, but I don't know whether there's a standardized way of doing it.)

As an aside, I'd also recommend implementing `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`, and using an executor service, so that threads can be reused.

Comment: I have same issue, Please review 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044187/struts2-execandwait-nullpointerexception