# Struts2 ExecAndWait NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, struts2

I have used `ExecuAndWait` in `Struts2`

I am getting error `NPE` while setting attribute in request in action(which is long running)

Here is stack track:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.notifyAttributeAssigned(Request.java:1563)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1554)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:542)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.setAttribute(ServletRequestWrapper.java:239)
    at com.os.gfnactions.SiteAction.createSite(SiteAction.java:1298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.os.interceptor.BackgroundProcess$1.run(BackgroundProcess.java:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Source snipate :**

> Action class:

```
public String createSite() throws Exception
    {
        ----

        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        request.setAttribute("test", "test"); {At this line I got error}
        ---
    }
```

From  [ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.2/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor.java)

```
231            if ((!executeAfterValidationPass || secondTime) && bp == null) {
232                bp = getNewBackgroundProcess(name, actionInvocation, threadPriority);
233                session.put(KEY + name, bp);
234                performInitialDelay(bp); // first time let some time pass before showing wait page
235                secondTime = false;
236            }
```

From [BackgroundProcess.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.1.2/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/BackgroundProcess.java)

```
public More ...BackgroundProcess(String threadName, final ActionInvocation invocation, int threadPriority) {
50         this.invocation = invocation;
51         this.action = invocation.getAction();
52         try {
53             final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
54                 public void More ...run() {
55                     try {
56                         beforeInvocation();
57                         result = invocation.invokeActionOnly();
58                         afterInvocation();
59                     } catch (Exception e) {
60                         exception = e;
61                     }
62 
63                     done = true;
64                 }
65             });
66             t.setName(threadName);
67             t.setPriority(threadPriority);
68             t.start();
69         } catch (Exception e) {
70             exception = e;
71         }
72     }
```

**Concept of Struts2 ExecuteAndWait** 
Whenever there is a long-running request, it going to execute in `separate thread` and result return `WAIT`, So again client resubmit the same request in some interval to know the status of its process(which is running in the thread)

**My Problem:** In above case when main request(Which initiate thread to invoke action) return with WAIT and again other request come to know status of action at this time in my action class I have `request.setAttribute("test", "test");`, at this line it throws an error which I have mention above.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `setAttribute` ?

Comment: based on `setAttribute value`, In my `Interceptor` I have decided which result shown in success case

Comment: Instead of request scope use a session scope.

Comment: Yes that I already did to solve this problem, But want to know about this behavior, If this working then I don't have to change request scope to session in whole product for long running action.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with `execAndWait` interceptor throwing `NPE`. You can find my case study here: [execAndWait interceptor not working with validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876965/execandwait-interceptor-not-working-with-validation/29877137) on how I solved this problem..  In this problem what I find out was, that `execAndWait` runs in separate thread and keeps throwing `wait` until action is completed and in mean time it cycles itself. I faced this problem, because I used `model driven` interceptor with it. Due to that the `getModel()` of model driven interceptor was repeatedly being called by `execAndWait` interceptor. In getModel method, it was setting the new POJO object again and again from scratch.

And then it was entering into `validate` method for validation. Inside validation process it found one of the POJO field to be null. Obviously, it happened due to re-creating of raw new POJO object in `getModel`. And thus was throwing `Null Pointer Exception`.

So what I did was I used `SessionAware` interface. And stored the POJO object for the first time when it entered `validate`. Because `execAndWait` will surely call all methods again and re-write an object from scratch. For this purpose I checked the availability of that object in `getModel()` method. If that found in session, then return that same object, rather of creating a new object.

I hope you'll find a way from this.